# How to customize wp_signon()

Tags: users, user-roles, user-registration, user-access, single-sign-on

I am trying to get a customized sign on process.

The features that are absent in WordPress by default are the following:

1. Allow user to choose a password at the time of registration.
2. Allow user to sign in using social networks particularly Facebook, Twitter and Google plus.
3. Verify user's Cell Phone number using sms for activating account.
4. Let the default role of every new user, irrespective of the sign in method, be elevated to `contributor`.
5. Upon successful log in, the user should be directed to his own personalized dashboard instead of the static home page.

So my questions are:

- I have looked at numerous plugins which provide social media log ins, but all of  them signup the user as a contributor. So, how do it change this behavior?
- How do I send both the email and sms verification before activating the account? Which hook do I need to use here?
- Once the user logs in successfully, how do I redirect him/her?
- How do I let the user select the password, or better still, present the user creation page seen by admin only to the anonymous user?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Theme My Login plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/)? It will do some of what you want, and you can customize it by writing a theme-my-login-custom.php file (assuming you know enough about PHP and Wordpress to do so).